# Android: Handling Internationalization/multi-language during runtime

Tags: android, internationalization

I'm implementing internationalization for my application. The main part of the internationalization is supporting multi-languages.

One approach for supporting multi-language is, creating multiple `values` directories under the `res/` directory and having strings.xml for the corresponding languages. Example [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html).

**But my requirement is something like this:**

The user enters his credentials to login to the application. Based on the language selected while creating an account on this app, the user would have selected a language.

So, on successful login, i'll be making a call to a service that will be returning all the strings in the application. And dynamically i must be associating these string to the labels in the application.

How can the above thing be done efficiently?

One approach that i have thought is, make a call to the service on successful login and store all the information on the Shared Preferences. and then use it.

Is there any other way to do this?
How do i change the text in cases of the xml layout files having `android:text=""`?

Please share your views regarding the same.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Change language programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programatically-in-android) . Whatever you do, you should use Android standard way (resources) instead of reinventing the wheel.

Update:
Due to your strange constraints, if you decide to reinvent the wheel, you could for example create derived classes using the TAG field of the views, something like:

```
public class LocalizableTextView extends TextView {


    public LocalizableTextView(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {

        super(ctx, attrs);
        setText(MyLocalizableStuff.get(this.getTag());
    }


}
```

and create a static helper class MyLocalizableStuff like this: (needs error checking, etc, just typed out of my head)

```
public static class MyLocalizableStuff {

    private static HashMap<Integer,String> sStringTable=new HashMap<>();

    public static String get(Object code) {

        Integer intCode=Integer.valueOf((String)code);
        String result=sStringTable.get(intCode);
        return result;
    }

    public static void init(Context ctx) {

        // read your strings and store them on the stringtable
        // you will call this init from onCreate like
        // MyLocalizableStuff.init(context)

    }


}
```

This way, you can insert `LocalizableTextViews` in your XML and assign a (numeric) TAG code that will map to the String and in construction time, will be assigned to the `TextView`. You could also use Strings as the code, but bear in mind that the HashMap will then be slower.

You could also use a `SparseArray` to store the string table instead of a `HashMap`, it will be probably faster.

But again, I wouldn't go this route.

Comment: Hi i need an approach that does not include resource files due to some specified constrains